# Netbeans and Redmine integration

Tags: api, netbeans, redmine, netbeans-plugins, redmine-plugins

Has anyone been able to successfully integrate netbeans with Redmine since the new rest API for Redmine has been released?

I have read a handful of articles written a while ago that suggest this new API will be the solution to the integration woes but as yet have been unsuccessful getting anything to work myself.

The idea would be to use Redmine as the bug tracker.

Comment: I have accepted Devon's answer because the linked API is what I am using on this -> https://github.com/tosbourn/Netbeans-Redmine-Integration

Comment: This was also asked on https://www.chiliproject.org/boards/1/topics/180?r=641
Chiliproject is a fork of Redmine

Comment: There's a feature request on Netbeans' bugzilla for adding Redmine support. Please vote for it: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=164174

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: The location of Redmine has changed.

Take a look at http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am not using Netbeans for java development and I think that is just so you can hook into redmine from inside a java app.

Comment: @Toby Ah, ok. Take a look at the Cubeon plugin. They have an open ticket for adding Redmine support. http://code.google.com/p/cubeon/issues/detail?id=51&q=redmine

Comment: Cheers - got tired of waiting and am currently writing my own. Been a while since I used java so should be fun!

Comment: the link is broken... :( Try using this: http://kenai.com/projects/redminenb/pages/Home

Answer (score 4):

The first alpha version of the **Redmine Plugin for NetBeans** has been released:

- http://anchialas.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/redmine-plugin-for-netbeans/
- http://kenai.com/projects/redminenb/pages/Home